# how to convert Uppercase to lower case and vice versa without using regexp in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am a complete beginner and I was trying to do this using loops and if conditionals, however it never worked, I am suspecting the problem is with my if conditional.

here is my code and thanks in advance.

```
function alter(a){






        for (var i = 0; i<a.length; i++){



            if (a[i] === a[i].toUpperCase()){ a[i] = a[i].toLowerCase(); }

            else if (a[i] === a[i].toLowerCase()){ a[i] = a[i].toUpperCase(); }

        }


        console.log(a);



}
```

Comment: You want to convert ALL characters of a string to either upper or lower case?

Comment: Strings are immutable.  You can't do that.

Comment: I got it - if it's upper you want it lower and vice versa.  Got it.

Comment: yes, I want to convert ALL uppercase letters to lower case and convert all lower case to uppser case
so that HeLLo become hEllO

Comment: @SLaks what do you mean by immutable, sorry I'm a beginner

Comment: he mean you cannot change a string you will need to create a new one but it is not a probleme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var hello = "hElLO";
var newWord = [];

for (i=0; i<hello.length; i++) {
  if (hello[i] == hello[i].toLowerCase()) {
      newWord[i] = hello[i].toUpperCase();
  }
  else {
    newWord[i] = hello[i].toLowerCase();
  }
}

alert(newWord.join(""));
```

Comment: Thank you so much JoeL. I was just wondering why would you create newWord as an array then join it but not create it as an empty string.does it also have to do with the fact that strings are immutable?

Comment: @MohamedHegazy Strings are immutable but the way bapibopi works as well. I just chose to an array with each character being an element to show another method of doing it as there are always multiple ways of achieving goals in coding.

Comment: yea I understood both and I actually had to learn the hard way that programming has infinite ways of achieving the same goal.

Answer (score 3):

As @SLaks mentioned, strings in javascript are immutable, meaning that you can't actually change the contents of one. Instead you could create a new empty string and add to that

```
function alter(string) {
  var newString = ''
  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    newString += string[i] === string[i].toUpperCase() ? string[i].toLowerCase() : string[i].toUpperCase()
  }
  return newString
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let str = 'HelloWorld';

let UPPER = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
    LOWER='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
    res1=[],len=str.length;

for(let i=0;i<len;i++){
  if(UPPER.indexOf(str[i])!==-1)
    res1.push(str[i].toLowerCase())
  else if(LOWER.indexOf(str[i]!==-1))
    res1.push(str[i].toUpperCase())
}
console.log('solution-1: '+res1.join(''))
 

let res2=[];
for(let i=0;i<len;i++){
    if(UPPER.includes(str[i]))
  res2.push(str[i].toLowerCase())
  else if(LOWER.includes(str[i]))
   res2.push(str[i].toUpperCase())
}

console.log('solution 2: '+res2.join(''))
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert uppercase to lower case and vice versa simply with ES6 feature

```js
const caseToggler = (str) => str.split('').map(item => item === item.toUpperCase() ? item.toLowerCase() : item.toUpperCase()).join('')

console.log(caseToggler('ab1By'))
```